# Geocode doesn't work - Genymotion

Tags: android, google-maps, geocoding, genymotion

I've tried to implement my project geocode in Genymotion emulator, but it doesn't work. However the map works perfectly.

1. Android build target : 4.2.2 With Google API
2. Genymotion : Galaxy Nexus 4.2.2 With Google Apps
3. And I've added the google-play-services_lib to my project

I've got this

> E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1954): The Google Play services resources were not found.
>   Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.

anyone have a solutions? Thanks

Comment: Have you downloaded and installed the Google Play Services on the emulator?

Comment: Are you using Eclipse or Android Studio (gradle) for the project? From the log you posted it looks like your project is not setup correctly.

Comment: @Egor i used genymotion galaxy nexus 4.2.2 with google apps so the default of emulator has google play services, isn't it?

Comment: @fasteque yes i use eclipse and i've completely install the setup so the map work perfectly

Answer (score 3):

The geocoder is notoriously unreliable on older devices (as well as on Genymotion so I use a helper class that works in all enviornments) as well as problematic in general as a class (and accuracy of results).

You can use google maps to do geolocation very easily,

An asynctask I wrote to use Geocoder first and fallback to a HttpRequest (using volley) if that fails is at https://gist.github.com/selecsosi/6705630

the relevant part:

Make a request to

```
"http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" + URLEncoder.encode(mAddress, "utf-8") + "&ka&sensor=false"
```

with mAddress being the location you are searching for.

That request will return you a JSON object you can parse like so

```
public static LatLng getLatLngFromGoogleJson(JSONObject jsonObject) {

    double lon = 0d;
    double lat = 0d;

    try {
        lon = ((JSONArray)jsonObject.get("results")).getJSONObject(0)
            .getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location")
            .getDouble("lng");

        lat = ((JSONArray)jsonObject.get("results")).getJSONObject(0)
            .getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location")
            .getDouble("lat");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        if(Log.isLoggable(TAG, Log.ERROR))Log.e(TAG, "Error parsing google response", e);
    }

    return new LatLng(lat, lon);
}
```

Comment: thanks for replied! but i want use the geocode for android :D

Comment: Np, i'm just telling you the geocode class doesn't work in geny, so this fallback uses the Geocoder when it exists (on regular android devices), and falls back to making a google maps http request when it is on the emulator (just to make my life more sane and not have to swap out code based on where I'm testing).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there is a way to install gapps in genymotion

i found this https://gist.github.com/wbroek/9321145

> Download the following ZIPs:
>
> ARM Translation Installer v1.1  (http://www.mirrorcreator.com/files/0ZIO8PME/Genymotion-ARM-Translation_v1.1.zip_links)
>
> Download the correct GApps for your Android version:
>
> Next Open your Genymotion VM and go to the Homescreen
>   Now Drag&Drop the Genymotion-ARM-Translation.zip onto the Genymotion VM window.
>
> It should say "File transfer in progress", once it asks you to flash it click 'OK'
>
> Now Reboot your VM using ADB. If nescessary you can simply close the VM window, not recommended
>
> Once you're on the Homescreen again Drag&Drop the gapps-jb-20130813-signed.zip (or whatever version you got) onto your VM, and click 'OK' when asked
>
> Once it finishes, again Reboot your VM and open the Google Play Store.
>
> Sign in using your Google account
>
> Once in the Store go to the 'My Apps' menu and let everything update (fixes a lot of issues), also try updating Google Play Services directly (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gms).
>   You can also search for Google Maps, update it manually (press update or install button) and you will receive the message to update Google Play Services
>   (For Android 4.4.4 and 5.0 is posible you need to reboot several times before updates are shown)

i recomend download gapps from

http://opengapps.org/  or  http://www.teamandroid.com/gapps/ but they are more version in the gist link